# How detect install click event in PWA dialog?

Tags: android, html, flutter, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I want to track the install event of the default PWA install dialog in a flutter.
So if do you have an idea about it how to track via service-worker or another way then please comment your answer.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own install UI, you can capture the  `beforeinstallprompt` event, and when the user clicks on your install button, you can capture the outcome of the install dialog:

```
// You save the prompt on the beforeinstallprompt event handler
// prompt will show the browser install pop dialog
deferredPrompt.prompt()

//Here you capture the outcome
const { outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;

//send the event to google analytics for tracking
ga('send', 'event', {
  eventCategory: 'pwa-install',
  eventAction: 'promo-clicked',
  eventValue: outcome === 'accepted' ? 1 : 0,
}
```

If you don't have your own install UI, on Edge and Chrome you can user the 'onappinstalled' event to capture the installation.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzJfiKQyD24&t=3s) has more details about the installation cycle and how to use google analytics to log events

Comment: Hi, @Adriana Jara thanks for your response, if you have more experience with that so can you please explain more in detail, please? I want to track, user click on the install button and if Mobile App already installs in the device then open app other wise installs PWA. in flutter.